# Correct int ID value redirect php

Tags: php

I am not sure if this is possible and I am really not sure how to ask the question.

if I have a auto increment uid and I start it at 1000 instead of 1 the link displays like this

> http://mywebsite.com/member.php?uid=1000

now on the member page I have add a redirect if there is no value for uid

```
<?php

if(empty($_GET['uid'])) {
    header("Location: http://localhost/website/");
    exit;
}
?>
```

my question is since the uid starts at 1000, how can I make redirect if id is under 1000? because if I change it to 999 in the url since 999 don't exist I get and error

Comment: `if(empty($_GET['uid']) || $_GET['uid'] <1000 )`

Comment: Mihai thank you so much can you post the answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple or condition

```
if(empty($_GET['uid']) || $_GET['uid'] <1000 )...
```